# PHP: extract comma separated values from MySQL

Tags: string-concatenation

my table is:

id | id_fruit | name

`2|1|orange|
3|1|apple|
23|1|banana|
34|1|ananas|
35|3|kiwi|`

I want to extract all name where id_fruit=1 and print them in a form field as values in this way:
orange, apple, banana, ananas

I've tried 
`select concat_ws(', ', name) from fruits where id_fruit=1` but doesn't work.
Ho can I do it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply through PHP, you can do like that! 
You can while loop all the names like this.

**PHP**

```
$in = 0;    
$fruits = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exeutedquery)){
if($i == 0){
$fruits += $row['name'];
$i++;
}else{
$fruits += ",".$row['name'];
}
}
```

**AND FOR SQL**

```
SELECT STUFF
(
     (select ',' + name
      from
      fruits
      where 
      ID in (1,2,3)
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,1,''
)
```

BAM!

Answer (score 0):

User Group_Contact function in mysql

Select group_concat(name) from my table where fruit_id=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the `concat_ws()` use.
[MySQL documentation about this function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) explains you must give every argument to join at once.
So you sql statement has no effect.

As Raja says, you can go with your back-end programming language (such as php, python or whatever you use).
You just `select` without the `concat_ws` and do the join on the back-end side.

It seems `concat_ws()` main use is to concat two fields from the same entry in mysql, such as the firstname and lastname (fields) for example of the same user (entry).